# ¿Como poner mas de un control en un TabItem de un TabControl?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, wpf, xaml

Estoy trabajando con WPF, Visual Studio 2015.

El problema que tengo es el siguiente tengo un TabControl con tabItems, en un tabitem he agregado un control label sin problemas pero cuando agrego otro label mas me da el siguiente mensaje: **"La propiedad content esta establecida mas de una vez.", en un tabItem solo puede aceptar un elemento secundario.**

```
<TabItem Header="Lista">
            <Label x:Name="label" Content="Nombre:" Margin="10,13,219,226"  />
            <Label x:Name="label1" Content="Label" Height="100" Width="100"/>
        </TabItem>
```

Para evitar ese error hice lo siguiente:

```
<TabItem Header="Lista">
            <Label x:Name="label1" Margin="10,13,219,226">Nombre:</Label>
            <Label x:Name="label2">Dirección:</Label>
        </TabItem>
```

Pero igual me sigue saliendo el mismo error, ¿De repente tenga que configurar el control TabControl?, ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Logré solucionarlo usando un panel que admita controles secundarios, puse un Canvas y dentro de el los labels, pero ¿no se si será la mejor solución?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En `wpf` tienes que usar contenedores como ser: `StackPanel`, `Grid`, etc

[Información general sobre controles contenedor de WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb514628(v=vs.90).aspx)

para poder ubicar mas de un control usarias

```
<TabItem Header="Lista">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label x:Name="label1" Margin="10,13,219,226">Nombre:</Label>
        <Label x:Name="label2">Dirección:</Label>
    </StackPanel>
</TabItem>
```

o si quieres controlar mejor el layout el grid te dara mas flexibilidad, como se explica aqui

[Tab Control in WPF](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prathore/tab-control-in-wpf/)